# Block anonymous users from uploading files to Windows/temp on Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

Anonymous users are able to upload files through a POST request to the C:/Windows/Temp folder on the server. The websites are the latest wordpress (4.4.1) running on a Windows 10 Server, IIS8, and PHP 5.6. How can files from anonymous users posting/uploading be blocked?

Comment: Please, read this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/292519 what you want to do, is remove those permissions